# Need a plain English explanation of Network Adapter Bindings section of Receive Connector on Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

There's a technical explanation of what "Receive connector local address bindings" are in this microsoft documentation page:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996395(v=exchg.160).aspx#Bindings

And I'm assuming that is describing the "same" functionality that appears in the *Network Adapter Bindings* section on the Receive Connector screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFVdA.jpg

I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around what these "bindings" do though.

Currently, you can see from my screenshot, that this receive connector for port 25 is "bound" to all IPv4 addresses on the local network.

What would happen if I set the connector's adapter bind IPv4 address to only be 192.168.1.1, and my Windows 8 client machines running Outlook 2013 had ip addresses of say 192.168.1.100 thru 192.168.1.110?  Would those client windows machines be unable to send and/or receive messages with Outlook, since the port 25 receive connector is not "bound" to those IP addresses?

What about if I have an internet-facing router, that has a LAN address of 192.168.1.2, but forwards all port 25 traffic from the outside world to my Exchange Server?  If I don't have 192.168.1.2 specified in that Network Adapter bindings section, would my Exchange Server stop receiving emails from the outside world?

Also, in that same scenario with router that port forwards - is that forwarded port 25 traffic from the outside world considered to be coming in from a remote server (and subject to the rules of the top half of my screenshot) or is it at that point considered LAN traffic and therefore subject to the rules of the bottom half of my screenshot?  I'd expect the former scenario, but I'm asking as a sanity check.

Thanks for your time with my rather specific questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would happen if I set the connector's adapter bind IPv4 address to only be 192.168.1.1, and my Windows 8 client machines running Outlook 2013 had ip addresses of say 192.168.1.100 thru 192.168.1.110? Would those client windows machines be unable to send and/or receive messages with Outlook, since the port 25 receive connector is not "bound" to those IP addresses?
>
> What about if I have an internet-facing router, that has a LAN address of 192.168.1.2, but forwards all port 25 traffic from the outside world to my Exchange Server? If I don't have 192.168.1.2 specified in that Network Adapter bindings section, would my Exchange Server stop receiving emails from the outside world?

You are thinking about it wrong.  This setting is in case the Exchange server has multiple IPs of its own, and you want to set the connector to only listen on a certain IP on the Exchange server.  For instance, if the server has two nics or multiple IPs assigned to it, you can set the Exchange connector to either listen on all its local IPs or it can be set to only listen on a certain IP for inbound emails to it.

The original client/source doesn't matter here, as long as it can "reach" the IP address configured on the listener.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  That does clarify things much easier, and that makes sense.